# Using a inherited class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In the following excerpt, how can I access the inherited `Sub` class template?

As far as I understand the problem with the constellation below is that the base class `Base` is itself a dependent class. Accessing it using `typename`/`template` works but is cumbersome if `Sub` is needed frequently.

```
template<int B>
struct Base {
    template<int S>
    class Sub { };
};

template<int C>
struct Class: public Base<C> {
    // (1) Error: 'Sub' does not name a type
    using S2 = Sub<2>;

    // (2) Error: 'Base' used without template argument list
    using S3 = Base::Sub<3>;

    // (3) Error: 'Class' is incomplete here
    using S4 = Class::Sub<4>

    // (4) Works, but complicated
    using S1 = typename Class::template Sub<1>;
};

using Class0 = Class<0>;
int main() { }
```

Fruther caveats:

- Is there a way to refer to `Sub` *without* having to duplicate the specialization for `Base`? I.e., consider `Base` having numerous/complex template arguments. This is basically why option #3 does not work and why I chose `Class` as qualification in option #4.

Comment: Just rethinking it, I started wondering why option #4 works, with `Class` still being incomplete at the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the *template* `Sub`, then you can go with option 5, an alias template:

```
template<int I>
using Sub = typename Base<C>::template Sub<I>;
```

Now `Sub` is found inside `Class` during unqualified name lookup, and is known to be a template. It will also stand exactly for the same type obtained from the base class member template, when a specialization is referred to.

<kbd>[**See it live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0488c6d15a9cf13b)</kbd>

Comment: Looks promising - For the sake of completeness, do you see an option to get rid of the template argument list for `Base`?

Comment: @Kamajii - Not possible. You want to refer to the template specialization that is `Class`'s base class, and that's `Base<C>`. But why should it matter? You already can use `Sub<1>` and so forth to refer to the exact same type you'd get from `typename Base<C>::template Sub<1>`.